# Task<T>.Result and string concatenation

Tags: c#, .net, c#-5.0

I was playing with `async / await` when I came across the following:

```
class C
{
    private static string str;

    private static async Task<int> FooAsync()
    {
        str += "2";
        await Task.Delay(100);
        str += "4";
        return 5;
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        str = "1";
        var t = FooAsync();
        str += "3";

        str += t.Result; // Line X

        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

I expected the result to be "12345", but it was "1235". Somehow '4' was eaten up.

If I split Line X into:

```
int i = t.Result;
str += i;
```

Then the expected "12345" results.

Why is it so? (Using VS2012)

Comment: The why is definitely interesting, but it should also be noted you should not do this - shared access to a variable with operations that are not atomic with no locks or other threading logic is sure to get you into indeterminate situations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a race condition.  You're not properly synchronizing access to the shared variable between the two threads of execution that you have.

Your code is probably doing something like this:

- sets the string to be "1"
- call FooAsync
- append 2
- when the await is called the main method continues executing, the callback in FooAsync will run in the thread pool; from here on out things are indeterminate.
- the main thread appends 3 to the string

Then we get to the interesting line:

```
str += t.Result;
```

Here it's broken up into several smaller operations.  It will first get the current value of `str`.  At this point in time the async method (in all probability) hasn't finished yet, so it'll be `"123"`.  It then waits for the task to complete (because `Result` forces a blocking wait) and adds the result of the task, in this case `5` to the end of the string.

The async callback will have grabbed and re-set `str` *after* the main thread had already grabbed the current value of `str`, and then it will overwrite `str` without it ever being read as the main thread is soon to overwrite it.

Answer (score 10):

> Why is it so? (Using VS2012)

You're running this in a console application, which means there is no current synchronization context.

As such, the portion of the `FooAsync()` method after the `await` runs in a separate thread.  When you do `str += t.Result` you're effectively making a race condition between the `+= 4` call, and the `+= t.Result`.  This is because `string +=` is not an atomic operation.

If you were to run the same code within a Windows Forms or WPF application, the synchronization context would be captured and used for the `+= "4"`, which means this would all run on the same thread, and you wouldn't see this issue.

Comment: How can there be a race condition if `return 5` happens **after** `str += 4` in the code of `FooAsync`?

Comment: @IlyaKogan Because `+=` isn't an atomic operation.  It's broken up into several sub-operations that can (and in this case are) being interwoven to generate undefined results.

Comment: @IlyaKogan The race condition occurs because `str += t.Result` is effectively `str = str + t.Result`, and "str" is fetched before `+=4` finishes.

Answer (score 7):

C# statements of the form `x += y;` are expanded to `x = x + y;` at compile time.

`str += t.Result;` becomes `str = str + t.Result;`, where `str` is read *before* getting `t.Result`. At this point in time, `str` is `"123"`. When the continuation in `FooAsync` runs, it modifies `str` and then returns `5`. So `str` is now `"1234"`. But then the value of `str` that was read *before* the continuation in `FooAsync` ran (which is `"123"`) is concatenated with `5` to assign to `str` the value `"1235"`.

When you break it into two statements, `int i = t.Result; str += i;`, this behavior can't happen.

Comment: The behavior can still happen when broken into two statements. It's just less likely. See Reed's answer.